# Не получается спарсить из поп-ап

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, beautiful-soup

Сайт: http://oto-register.autoins.ru/oto/index.xhtml
Нужно спарсить: категории, чтобы к ним прийти — жмем на галочку.

Зашел через Selenium + soap, но почему-то не находит элементы

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chromedriver="chromedriver"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get("http://oto-register.autoins.ru/oto/index.xhtml")

pages = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("a.ui-commandlink")

pg_list = []
for page in pages:
    try:
        pg_list.append(int(page.text))
    except:
        continue
urls=[]
credits=[]
table = pd.DataFrame()
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
elems = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("td.footable-first-visible a")
for el in elems:
    a = el.get_attribute("href")
    url ={
        "href":a
    }
    urls.append(url)
for j in urls:
    browser.get(j["href"])
    bbs = str(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("span.green-text"))
    print(bbs)
```

Comment: Посмотрел на запрос при клике, там используется POST запрос, а не GET и еще нужно кучу полей формы заполнить: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPxF5.png

Comment: пока я понял, что мне нужно использовать selenium+soup

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы находило, сделал такую конструкцию и всё заработало

```
for element in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr:nth-child(1) .green-text'):
                simple_list.append([element.text])
```